# What is the difference between Minecraft: Java Edition and Educational Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-education-edition

I've heard of Minecraft Education Edition before, and my school's Microsoft account was eligible to play it for free. But is it any different from the regular Minecraft Java/Bedrock Edition? Can mods be used in the Education Edition? Can you go to the Nether as well? If there is a difference, and if so, what is it?
What I know so far is that there isn't multiplayer, and the "Realms" button, but what is different in the actual Survival / Creative mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Minecraft Education Edition**](https://education.minecraft.net/) is focused on classroom use, so that students can learn while playing, with special blocks and commands, chat/conversation systems, classroom mode and more. It's more similar to the [Bedrock Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition) rather than [Java Edition](https://www.minecraft.net/). Mods aren't available at [Minecraft Education Edition](https://education.minecraft.net/), as said [here](https://education.minecraft.net/faq/mods/).

On the other hand, Minecraft [Java](https://www.minecraft.net/)/[Bedrock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition) are games without direct educational purposes.

So, there **are** differences in both modes. As you can use it without any cost, I suggest you give it a try.

*The best way to understand something is to do it.* :3

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft Education Edition is more focus on Education.
You also need to have an account of Office 365 Education if you wann to log in To the Minecraft Education Edition.
Thing Realms, Multiplayer Servers or achievements are not in Minecraft Education Edition.
Minecraft Education Edition Adds NPC (Non Player Characters) Boards, Deny, Allow Blocks,
Code Builder, Chemistry Pack, Free Skins, and Free Maps to Play